# "*** missing seperator" error in LZMA's makefile

Tags: makefile, lzma

I am trying to build the LZMA 18.05 library on Ubuntu 18.04, but here's what happens when I run `make` in `C/Util/LzmaLib`:

make
makefile:26: *** missing seperator. Stop.

I really don't understand what could be causing this as I am not the one who made the code, but rather a well known library. Here's line 26:

```
!include "../../../CPP/Build.mak"
```

Below is the code for the makefile in question:

```
MY_STATIC_LINK=1
SLIB = sLZMA.lib
PROG = LZMA.dll
SLIBPATH = $O\$(SLIB)

DEF_FILE = LzmaLib.def
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) \

LIB_OBJS = \
  $O\LzmaLibExports.obj \

C_OBJS = \
  $O\Alloc.obj \
  $O\LzFind.obj \
  $O\LzFindMt.obj \
  $O\LzmaDec.obj \
  $O\LzmaEnc.obj \
  $O\LzmaLib.obj \
  $O\Threads.obj \

OBJS = \
  $(LIB_OBJS) \
  $(C_OBJS) \
  $O\resource.res

!include "../../../CPP/Build.mak"

$(SLIBPATH): $O $(OBJS)
    lib -out:$(SLIBPATH) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

$(LIB_OBJS): $(*B).c
    $(COMPL_O2)
$(C_OBJS): ../../$(*B).c
    $(COMPL_O2)
```

Any idea how to fix this? If you need more, [here's the download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/LZMA%20SDK/lzma1805.7z/download) to the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a GNU makefile. I think it's for nmake on Windows. The other stuff (`obj`, `def`, `lib`, `dll` and a resource file) also points to a Windows library build, so just patching up the include syntax isn't enough. This doesn't look like something that's meant to build on Unix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would have never found that by myself. Do you have any idea where I could find LZMA 18.05 for linux? I've been looking for quite some time and haven't found it.

Comment: @JigsawCorp, As far as I can tell, the LZMA SDK is a Windows-only project.  But its [main download page](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) contains links to a companion project for Linux, [p7zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/). Dunno whether that will be everything you need or how well it works, but it's probably a better starting point for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm making a Linux version of a Windows projet we currently have that uses LZMA. So if I use another library, I'll have to re-write all portions that made calls to LZMA since the calls are mostly library dependent. 

I guess I'll have to work with those limitations.